# Disable edit feature in gerrit change

Tags: gerrit

I am recently using Gerrit and starting to play with different features. I figure out that [editing a change](https://gerrit-review.googlesource.com/Documentation/user-inline-edit.html) may cause some issues like following :

1. After submitting the edited change, the commiter get a conflict when pulling the remote.
2. On my machine, gerrit changes some character encode. It increase the number of line changed.

The question is : **Is it possible to disable the edit feature in Gerrit** ?

I didn't find the feature in access configuration of `Project All-Projects`

Answer (score 0):

Gerrit does not have this feature at present. Since it's free and open source, you could modify its source code to disable the edit button. There is another edit entry on the side-by-side diff view.

The committer must abandon the previous commit in the local since it's not merged into the remote branch, and reset the local HEAD to the new patch-set/commit before next `git pull`, via commands like

```
git fetch origin refs/changes/zz/xxxzz/y && git reset FETCH_HEAD --hard
```

or

```
git fetch origin <branch> && git checkout -b <branch> FETCH_HEAD
```

As to your 2nd problem, I think there is some config about encoding or crlf.

Comment: Do you have example or patch to remove this feature ? For now, I will leave with the feature enable.